# Why double.TryParse("0.0000", out doubleValue) returns false ?

Tags: c#, parsing, double

I am trying to parse string "0.0000" with `double.TryParse()` but I have no idea why would it return false in this particular example. When I pass integer-like strings e.g. "5" it parses correctly to value of 5 .

Any ideas why it is happening ?

Comment: it take the localization settings at runtime into account... perhaps you are running whis on a system where `.` is not the decimal point but `,` instead ?

Comment: @Yahia: Suggest you make that an answer (and include overload that takes an `IFormatProvider` so the culture can be specified).

Comment: Perhaps you chose the wrong culture. `TryParse` uses the current culture by default. (An idiotic decision IMO, but it's too late now to change it)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

it takes the localization settings at runtime into account... perhaps you are running this on a system where `.` is not the decimal point but `,` instead...

In your specific case I assume you want a fixed culture regardless of the system you are running on with `.` as the decimal point:

```
double.TryParse("0.0000", NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture ("en-US"), out temp)
```

OR

```
double.TryParse("0.0000", NumberStyles.Number,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out temp)
```

Some MSDN reference links:

- [Double.TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx)
- [CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx)
- [IFormatProvider Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)
- [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

`TryParse` uses the current culture by default. And if your current culture uses a decimal seperator different from `.`, it can't parse `0.0000` as you intend. So you need to pass in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

```
var numberStyle = NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite |
                 NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |
                 NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign |
                 NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint |
                 NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
                 NumberStyles.AllowExponent;//Choose what you need
double.TryParse( "0.0000", numberStyle, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myVar)
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly the problem is that `Thread.CurrentCulture` does not use dot as the decimal separator.

If you know that the number will be always formatted with dot as the decimal separator, use this code that utilizes [the other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) of `double.TryParse`:

```
style = NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
float num;
if (double.TryParse("0.0000", style, culture, out num)) {
    // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will return `false` if the current culture specifies a decimal point separator that is different than the `.` character.

When parsing strings representation you need to be aware in what culture they are represented otherwise you'll get unexpected behavior.

In this case you're getting `false`, but it could even be worse, for example in the following example if you were expecting to get the number one you would instead get one thousand:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");

double d;
Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse("1.000", out d));
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

This is because in the `pt-PT` culture the `.` character is used as `NumberGroupSeparator` and the `,` character is used as `NumberDecimalSeparator`.

If the input you're parsing comes from the user then always parse it using the culture the user is associated. Getting the culture the user is associated is something dependent on the context, for example in a Windows Forms application you would use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` when on the UI thread to get it. In a ASP.NET application this may be different.

Answer (score 1):

To change the culture to something that has "." as decimal separator use:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Comment: Changing the current culture is a bit ugly. Especially since you should save and restore it. And then you need to take care of exceptions...

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I was thinking that maybe he needs app-wide, or at least thread-wide parsing of doubles in the same manner. So it helps him to avoid passing the culture to every parse method he calls.

Answer (score 1):

> When this method returns, contains the double-precision floating-point
>   number equivalent to the s parameter, if the conversion succeeded, or
>   zero if the conversion failed.

From the MSDN page for this method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx

Zero goes in, zero comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the CultureInfo with TryParse did nothing for me. I had to change the number formats under Control Panel (Change, date, time, or number formats) and changed the Decimal symbol. Than it worked again.

Answer (score -2):

The most stupid thing about this is that it only accept "," as decimal separator in my culture, but the result is with a ".". Someone, somewhere, wasn't very lucky thinking that day...
So I'll try this:

```
if ((double.TryParse(sVat, out vat)) == false)
    if (double.TryParse(sVat.Replace(",", "."), out vat) == false)
      double.TryParse(sVat.Replace(".", ","), out vat);
```

Comment: "I'll try this"  Is this an answer?  Does it work? If don't say "I'll try this".

Answer (score -3):

It works for me:

```
double temp = 0;
Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse("0.0000", out temp));
Console.ReadLine();
```

writes `True`.