# Error Message TryParse

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, calculator, tryparse

I am struggling with my TryParse method. The program is to calculate the total rainfall and average rainfall. User enters each month in inches. The totals are accurate, but the error message "enter numeric value" pops up when you click calculate. The program also calculates with a symbol or letter, how would i go about stopping it at that point.

```
Public Class Korszun

    Private Sub Korszun_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter each month's rainfall average (ex: 1.11 inches)")
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtJuly_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtJuly.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtOctober_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtOctober.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        'declare the variables
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0
        Dim dblAverageRainfall As Double
        Dim dblTotalRainfall As Double
        Dim dblInches As Double

        'create txtbox variable
        'go through each TextBox control in the Groupbox and add them all up
        For Each txtBox As TextBox In Me.GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()

            If Not Double.TryParse(txtBox.Text, dblInches) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter numerical values only.")

            ElseIf CDbl(txtBox.Text) < 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter all positive numbers.")

            ElseIf TypeOf txtBox Is TextBox Then
                'add the total value of rainfall and put it in the decTotalRainfall variable
                dblTotalRainfall += CDbl(txtBox.Text)
            End If
        Next

        'get the average
        dblAverageRainfall = dblTotalRainfall / 12

        'show the results in the labels
        lblTotal.Text = dblTotalRainfall.ToString("n2")
        lblAverage.Text = dblAverageRainfall.ToString("n5")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        'Clear the Textboxes
        txtJanuary.Clear()
        txtFebruary.Clear()
        txtMarch.Clear()
        txtApril.Clear()
        txtMay.Clear()
        txtJune.Clear()
        txtJuly.Clear()
        txtAugust.Clear()
        txtSeptember.Clear()
        txtOctober.Clear()
        txtNovember.Clear()
        txtDecember.Clear()
        lblAverage.Clear()
        lblTotal.Clear()
        'Set focus
        txtJanuary.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtAverage_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblAverage.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is the textbox blank at any point? Does it have characters that cannot be parsed as numeric?

Comment: Are there any TextBoxes in GroupBox1 that do not contain a numeric value? If you thing not, try using the debugger to step though the loop and find which TextBox is causing the error.

Comment: Stopping the message? Simple. Comment out the line that shows you a message with an apostrophe. A better way would be to handle the input values of the textbox and cancel any keydown event when they key that was pressed isn't a valid input character. This would prevent the user from being allowed to input invalid data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463584/why-double-tryparse0-0000-out-doublevalue-returns-false

Comment: the final two labels are being read by the loop. They are intended to be blank to give the answer. I need to figure out how to bypass them when i click calculate

Comment: @jkorszun: The loop will not process Labels, you are limiting it to just the TextBoxes within GroupBox1. Is it possible that the controls called lblAverage and lblTotal are really TextBoxes and not Labels? If so, change them to Labels or place them outside GroupBox1.